# Android Studio does not start after updating

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, crash

I am using Linux Mint 17. I updated to android studio and after did not start.
How can I solve this ?

This is the error

[image: 1]

Comment: Delete IDE system/plugins folders (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519).

Comment: There is no plugin folder